# Global distribution/High latency in other regions with AWS AppSync

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, serverless, aws-appsync

**ISSUE** - High latency with AWS Cloudfront on top of AWS AppSync whereas AWS API Gateway (edge optimized) with AWS AppSync showing better results (low latency).

> If AWS gateway internally uses cloud front for global distribution
> then result should be same?
>
> Is it a best practice to use API Gateway on top of AppSync just for
> global distribution ?

In order to find the problem I tried multiple PoCs -

**POC 1 - High TTFB with ASIA region without AWS Cloudfront**

**Detail** - AWS AppSync deployed in us-east-1 region

**Screenshot** -

[image]

**POC 2 - High TTFB with ASIA region with AWS CloudFront on top of AWS AppSync**

**Detail** - AWS AppSync deployed in us-east-1 region, used AWS CloudFront (All edge locations) to solve global distribution and persistent connection for faster connections and data compression

**Result** - 10% improvement in latency but no data-compression got

**Screenshot** -
[image]

**POC 3 - Low TTFB in ASIA region with AWS Gatway (edge optimized) on top of AWS AppSync**

**Detail** - AWS Gateway deployed in us-east-1 region with edge-optimized which internally uses AWS CloudFront for persistent connection

**Result** - 30% improvement in latency with data compression

**Screenshot** -
[image]